# Persist Marker state on point click -Treemap - Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on TreeMap where I am able to give borderColor on Hover of a particular datapoint. The same in this fiddle link --> http://jsfiddle.net/vgnshs/z8ncv2d5/.

But I am in need of requirement where I should get same kind of borderColor on click of a particular dataPoint (saying to user that the Point is selected) and borderColor should persist until I click on the same point again or somewhere outside plotArea. (I see this feature is available in Bubble chart, same needed in TreeMap). Also I should be able to select multiple points and all selected points should have the same borderColor.

Currently, TreeMap's select event fills the entire point with a different color which I don't want to. Only borderColor should be changed. How can I achieve this in TreeMap?

```js
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        "chart": {
            "width": 640,
                "height": 480
        },
            "colorAxis": {
            "minColor": "#202020",
                "maxColor": "#B0B0B0"
        },
            "title": {
            "text": "Datalabel Sample"
        },
            "subtitle": {
            "text": null
        },
            "credits": {
            "enabled": false
        },
            "tooltip": {
            "enabled": false
        },
            "plotOptions": {
            "series": {
                "states": {
                    "hover": {
                        "borderColor": "#0000FF",
                            "borderWidth": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
            "legend": {
            "align": "right",
                "layout": "vertical",
                "verticalAlign": "middle",
                "symbolHeight": 380,
                "enabled": true
        },
            "series": [{
            "type": "treemap",
                "layoutAlgorithm": "squarified",
                "allowDrillToNode": true,
                "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": false
            },
                "levels": [{
                "level": 1,
                    "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": true,
                        "color": "#FFFFFF",
                        "allowOverlap": false,
                        "align": "center",
                        "style": {
                        "fontWeight": "normal",
                            "fontSize": "24px",
                            "fontStyle": "normal",
                            "fontFamily": "'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                            "textShadow": null
                    },
                        "overflow": false
                },
                    "borderWidth": 1
            }],
                "data": [ {
                "id": "Apparel",
                    "name": "Apparel",
                    "value": 130.1,
                    "colorValue": 130.1,
                    "expanded": false,
                    "canexpand": false
            }, {
                "id": "Footwear",
                    "name": "Footwear",
                    "value": 90.7,
                    "colorValue": 90.7,
                    "expanded": false,
                    "canexpand": true
            }, {
                "id": "Accessories",
                    "name": "Accessories",
                    "value": 180.5,
                    "colorValue": 180.5,
                    "expanded": false,
                    "canexpand": true
            }]
        }]

    });

});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set select state and configure `color as false`. Next step is configure datalabels, by setting `useHTML as true and zIndex as 30`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8ncv2d5/3/

Comment: That works cool. But forgot to mention one more point in the above question. Is it possible to dim out other dataPoints that are not selected ? (something like changing opacity of unselected datapoints, so that focus in on only selected dataPoints). If this is also possible in addition to above reply, my requirement is fulfilled :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you can set for all series custom colors (by rgba(122,122,122,0.5)) where last param is opacity. For select state set a color  rgba(122,122,122,1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian. Will investigate the sane. Thanks a lot. Love the response speed from Highcharts guys. :) You Guys Rock.

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/vgnshs/z8ncv2d5/) I am able to change opacity of selected points. But I need other way round. I need to reduce opacity of unselected points, so that user focuses on selected point only. While other unselected points opacity is reduced, selected points should have a blue border to indicate thats selected.

Comment: You can only use a workaround by setting a color of series by rgba.